# Erro 500 ao usar rewrite com o mesmo nome do arquivo (/tag/ não vai pra /tags.php)

Tags: apache, htaccess

Migrei recentemente meu servidor pra Ubuntu 14.04 com PHP 5.5.9 e Apache/2.4.7, porém o rewrite que tem string com nome de arquivo simplesmente não funciona.

Erro 500
`RewriteRule ^tag/?(.*)/?$ /tags.php?tag=$1 [L]`

Funciona
`RewriteRule ^tag/?(.*)/?$ /atags.php?tag=$1 [L]`

meu apache.conf

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solução:

```
RewriteRule ^tag/(.*)/?$ /tags.php?tag=$1 [L]
```